# Convergence or Divergence proving: $\int_a^b x\sqrt\frac{x-a}{b-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have some integral, b > a $$\int_a^b x\sqrt\frac{x-a}{b-x}dx$$
I tried to use the comparison test, but can't find right integral.

Which way I can prove Convergence or Divergence this integral?

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1 x^{-1/2}\,dx=$??

Comment: To be ever so slightly more explicit, the only infinity in the integrand is at $x=b$.  Thus you need to know if $\int_a^b (b-x)^{-1/2}\,dx$ converges.  Consider what the antiderivative of $x^{-1/2}$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist a constant $A > 0$ such that
\[
x\sqrt{x - a} \leq A
\]
for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Thus, the given integral is bounded by
\[
\leq A \int_{a}^{b}(b - x)^{-1/2}dx.
\]

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Substitution
$$\sqrt\frac{x-a}{b-x} = t,\quad x = {a+bt^2\over 1+t^2} = b+{a-b\over 1+t^2},\quad dx={2(b-a)\over(1+t^2)^2}\,tdt$$
gives converges integral
$$\int\limits_a^b x\sqrt\frac{x-a}{b-x}dx = \int\limits_0^\infty {2(a+bt^2)t^2\over(1+t^2)^3}dt$$